# Getting an error while trying to clone a repo from Azure DevOps project using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error while trying to clone a repo using VS Code in Windows 10. 
Visual Studio Code
Git: remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier  does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

The developer has full permission to the repo and the project does exist in Azure DevOps.

Thank you for your help

Pedro Reinoso

Comment: Welcome to SO. show some screenshoot or the error itself.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help.  We were able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found a working solution here - [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

I has a wrong git credentials saved in Credential Manager

- Open Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager\WindowsCredentials
- Find git credentials

[image]

- Remove credentials
- Try to clone again -> you will be asked for login
- Everything works ok

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue following another link in SO.  It had to do with clearing the Git credentials in the PC affected.  Below is the link we followed to resolve the issue:

[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a similar issue few days ago. In order to solve this I removed the git credential from windows credential manager and it worked..